# How do i continuously rotate a photo using Javascript function

Tags: javascript, css, image, rotation, logic

I'm trying to figure out logic to continuously rotate an image in Javascript. So far I have came up to this code. *img1* is the id of the image and so far it works but it rotates only once. How do I make it rotate every time I click on it? Im using *onclick* event.

```
function rotateProfilePic() {
            var image = document.getElementById('img1');
            image.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
        }
```

Sorry if the question is too simple for someone, I'm beginner in Web Programming.

Comment: You want to rotate image after clicking on it by moving the mouse or just rotate it on every click?

Comment: Rotate on every click, as said with onclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your function as clicks listener on image:

```
const imgTag = document.getElementById("img1");
const rotateStep = 180; // rotation size
let curImgAngle = 0;


function rotateProfilePic() {
  curImgAngle += rotateStep;
  imgTag.style.transform = `rotate(${curImgAngle}deg)`;
} 

imgTag.addEventListener("click", rotateProfilePic);
```

Comment: No problem, we all were learning in our time )